# Why doesn't std::cin.clear() work in this simple program?

Tags: c++, iostream

I was solving some exercises to pass the time, and I encountered a behaviour I didn't understand, I am going to explain:

The exercise:

> Write a program that reads and stores a series of integers and then computes the sum of the first `N` integers. First, ask for `N`, then read the values into a vector, then calculate the sum of the first `N` values.

Since I asked for `N` as the second step:

In the second `std::cin` (`std::cin >> values_to_compute`) it has to leave the while statement to continue the program, "only possible if" what is read is not a double. So I can type, for example; 'k' or "how are you?" or Ctrl + Z (I am on Windows 10).

```
int main() {
    try {
        double holder {0};
        std::vector<double> values;
        while (std::cin >> holder) {
            values.push_back(holder);
        }
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cout << "Out of the loop, now entering to the other std::cin\n";
        int values_to_compute {0};
        std::cin >> values_to_compute;
        std::cout << "Computing...\n";
        double result_computed {0};
        for (int i {0}; i < values_to_compute; ++i) {
            result_computed += values[i];
        }
        std::cout << "Result computed " << result_computed << '\n';

        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';

        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Ok so?
So... `std::cin` leaves the while in a not good() state. I have to call `std::cin.clear()` to be able to use `std::cin` again.

Ok, and?
Well, if I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to exit the `while` loop, the `std::cin.clear()` works; if I type something that is not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> the `std::cin.clear()` doesn't work.

I want to know the why of that behaviour.

Comment: " First ask for N," - your program doesn't do this. Why not?

Comment: I did not realize I wasn't following the instructions exactly until I had the "error". I leave it like that to know the why of the behaviour explained above :o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `std::cin::clear` clears the error state of `cin` but it *does not* remove the data from the stream. You can use `std::cin::ignore()` to read and discard a line of text before reading `values_to_compute`.

```
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Make sure to `#include <limits>` to get `std::numeric_limits`.